# Getting data inside of button. BS4 + Requests

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

`<button class="add-to-cart btn btn-primary" data-buttontext="Add to Cart" data-gtmdata='{"productInfo":{"sku":"225169","productID":"11108140","name":"PlayStation 5","category":"Video Games/PlayStation 5/Consoles","brand":"Sony","subGenre":"","platform":"PlayStation 5","condition":"New","variant":"New","genre":"","availability":"Not Available","productType":"regular","zoneSource":"PDP"},"price":{"sellingPrice":"499.99","basePrice":"499.99","currency":"USD"}}' data-pid="11108140" disabled=""> </button>`

Trying to get "availability":"Not Available" from this.

```
import requests
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
header = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"}
GameStopItem = 'https://www.gamestop.com/video-games/playstation-5/consoles/products/playstation-5/11108140.html'
r = requests.get(GameStopItem, headers=header)
r = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
GameStopStock = r.find(class_="add-to-cart btn btn-primary")
print(GameStopStock)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a `403 Forbidden` status with your code. Maybe you can have access whereas I can't. If that's the case, and you can use a code like this:

```py
# Similate your content as a soup
content = """<button class="add-to-cart btn btn-primary" data-buttontext="Add to Cart" data-gtmdata='{"productInfo":{"sku":"225169","productID":"11108140","name":"PlayStation 5","category":"Video Games/PlayStation 5/Consoles","brand":"Sony","subGenre":"","platform":"PlayStation 5","condition":"New","variant":"New","genre":"","availability":"Not Available","productType":"regular","zoneSource":"PDP"},"price":{"sellingPrice":"499.99","basePrice":"499.99","currency":"USD"}}' data-pid="11108140" disabled=""> </button>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(content)

# Get data from button as a dictionary:
product = eval(soup.find('button', class_='add-to-cart btn btn-primary').get('data-gtmdata'))

# And retrieve availability
product['productInfo']['availability']
```